# How to divide the price by 2 using JS

Tags: javascript

**How to divide the price by 2 using JS? I tried this but it didn't work.**

```
<script>
const a = parseInt(document.getElementById('price_value').textContent)
const b = 2
const result = a / b

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
</script>

<body>
<span class="wcpa_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span><span class="price_value">29.00</span></span>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 things:

- the `script` tag must be below the elements. Otherwise, when the script ran, the elements would not have been loaded yet.
- There is no element with the id `price_value`. You should be selecting the element with that class instead.

```html
<body>
<span class="wcpa_price"><span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">$</span><span class="price_value">29.00</span></span>
<div id="result"></div>
<script>
const a = parseInt(document.querySelector('.price_value').textContent)
const b = 2
const result = a / b

document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = result
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot. there is an improvement. but somehow I get 0 instead of the price divided...

Comment: @bohdanbohdan Have you tried running the snippet? It doesn't show 0 for me.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is that you do not have element with id price value but you have class on it called like that.

Issue is here:

```
document.getElementById('price_value')
```

To fix this add id "price_value" on the span element of the price.